# Linux Shell: useradd options

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command

Could anybody give me a little help with the following line:

```
sudo useradd -c USERNAME new_user | passwd new_user
```

What I am trying to do is add a new user to the system and set up their password all in one line without having to do two commands. When I enter this line it tells me that the user new_user does not exist. Could anybody help me out here or explain to me why this is not working?

Also if there is a better way of doing this then please feel free to let me know.

Thanks you,
Alex

Comment: This would probably be a better question at [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com), [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 2):

For interactive password entry the one-liner could be:

```
sudo $SHELL -c "useradd UNAME && passwd UNAME"
```

For pre-defined password you could do something like:

```
useradd -p $(mkpasswd --method=sha-512 --rounds=10 SECRET) UNAME
```

However, I'd suggest against that :)

To learn what encryption method is used on your system you can peek at `/etc/shadow`: if the hash begins with `$6$`- it is SHA-512 (as in the example).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the -p option to useradd

```
sudo useradd -c USERNAME -p new_password new_user
```

Comment: It does not recognise the -p.

Comment: Apologies, the parameters should come before the userid.  I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -p option of the useradd command, but you need to provide the encrypted password, for example making use of openssl library:

```
sudo useradd -c USERNAME new_user -p $(openssl passwd -crypt new_user_password)
```

You can also use other encryption methods but you cannot use a clear password since useradd manual states that -p parameter takes "The encrypted password as returned by crypt(3)".

Comment: Thanks for posting this, however it is telling me that -p is unknown. Could it be that there is an issue with the format of that line?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one

adduser username;passwd username;